# Is it true that stabilizer in $O(n)$ of a rank $k$ matrix is isomorphic to $O(n-k)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

Let $X\in M_{n, k}(\mathbb R)$ such that $\textrm{rank}(X)=k$ and,$$O(n)_X:=\{A\in O(n): AX=X\}.$$ Notice $O(n)_X$ is a subgroup of $O(n)$. Is it true that $O(n-k)\cong O(n)_X$? Here $O(n)=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb R): A^TA=I\}$..

Comment: How are the two $A$s supposed to relate? Also, would you mind explaining what $O(n)$ means?

Comment: @dfeuer I add what $O(n)$ means..

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes (except when $n=k$, where $O(0)$ is undefined). Geometrically, this is because $A$ fixes all $k$-columns of $X$ and it is free to perform any orthogonal transform on the orthogonal complement of the column space of $X$.

Comment: Great, do you have any idea of how to showing they are isomorphic?

Comment: @PtF Simply construct the isomorhpism! Let $v_1,\ldots,v_{n-k}$ be a orthonormal basis of the orthogonal complement of the column space of $X$, and $e_1,\ldots,e_{n-k}$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$. For every orthogonal $A$ that fixes $X$, let $Av_j=\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}a_{ij}v_i$ and define $f(A)=Q$ where $Qe_j=\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}a_{ij}e_i$. Then $Q\in O(n-k)$ and $f$ is an isomorphism.